# Constrain multi-output neural net to 100%

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic

I am looking to simultaneously output a set of resource allocations as percentages of a whole. Specifically I am looking at currency usage shares in international payments by country.

I have a panel set of input variables and I am looking to predict what share of a countries total international payments is denominated in each currency in each time step. This requires that the model output 35 response variables (one for each currency) and that these outputs all add to 100% while each value is also on the unit interval.

It seems to me that simultaneously outputting all shares is the best approach which also seems to lend itself to a neural net implementation but I tend to get predictions and results that are impossible given the constraints on the output.

I am wondering what might be the best way to model this relationship and if there is an activation function or architecture that might lend itself to these output constraints.

Comment: Why not just use softmax? The output of the softmax function is constrained to be non-negative and sum to 1.

Comment: I tried this but dont have much experience using the softmax. I only received predictions of zeros and a single 1 value so I was concerned this was functioning as a classification or rather than providing a "regression" output. This may be an issue in my model learning other than the activation I suppose.

Comment: When you say "prediction," are you processing the probability vector to put a 1 in the position of the largest probability, and 0 otherwise? Or are you saying that you have one value near to 1 and the rest near to 0?

Comment: I did not do any other processing but I get a values very very near 0 and 1 (out to at least 11 decimals)

Comment: Is your target variable in [0,1] also? What loss function are you using?

Comment: The target variable is a vector of currency shares which all sum to 100% for example [USD 55%, EUR 30%, GBP 15%] and I am using mean squared error for the loss function

Comment: Well.... there's the problem. You're computing the square error between a probability vector and a vector 100x as large. You'll either want to re-scale the softmax output to be a percentage or res-cale your target to be a proportion instead of a percent.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misunderstand or was not clear. The vector consists only of elements in unit scale, so precisely the vector I described would be [0.55, 0.30, 0.15] with my limited understanding of the softmax this seems in line

Comment: Got it. So you're still getting values that are all concentrated in 1 value; seems like it might just be a training issue. Alternatively, you could not use softmax, treat it as a regression problem that gives non-negative predictions, and then re-norm the predictions.

Comment: Thanks! As I have been looking at it more the softmax does indicate USD as the "one" in all cases which makes some sense given that USD is 70% or more of most of the observations so my problem may just be more complex than my current architecture can do anything with.

Comment: Another option is to transform your target to be logits and doing a plain old multi-target regression on the logits. Might have to be careful if there are 0s in your vector of target proportions, though.